# Why is .call() necessary when I want to see returned values from a function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

In my contract I have this function (solc 0.8.4):

```
    function makeDecision(address person) external returns (string memory name, bool approved) {
        require(msg.sender == loanOfficer, "Only the loan officer can initiate a decision.");
        require(bytes(applicants[person].name).length != 0, "That person is not in the pool of applicants.");

        if (applicants[person].credScore > 650 && applicants[person].credAge > 5) {
           applicants[person].approved = true;
        }

        return (applicants[person].name, applicants[person].approved);
}
```

When I go into my truffle console and call my function this way `loanContract.makeDecision(accounts[1])` everything works fine, but I get a tx receipt as the response.

When I call my function this way via truffle console `loanContract.makeDecision.call(accounts[1])` I get the expected response from my function. I am wanting an explanation that tells me why this difference in response occurs so that I understand what is going on on a deeper level. I hate using things without understanding why they work.

If it helps, my contract (which is named `LoanDisbursement`) was initialized in the console like so: `let loanContract = await LoanDisbursement.deployed()`
and my accounts variable: `let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()`

any tips would help since I am still learning and diving into this ecosystem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State-changing transactions do not alter the state until the transaction is mined. It's not possible to know the result until the transaction is confirmed because the result *may* depend on initial conditions and conditions *may* change between sending and confirmation. Return values are available to other contracts in the case of chain of interactions because those all execute in the context of the mined transaction.

Read-only calls merely inspect the current state.

This description is a little old and some of the terminology feels a little outdated but the principle is still true.

https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps

Comment: I think I understand. So, regarding the linked article, when I use ‘.call()’ that can be considered a local “what-if” scenario and the transaction isn’t verified by the rest of the block chain? But when I invoke the function the first way, that is actually performing the state change and sending it to the rest of the network which is why I get a transaction body as a response?

Comment: Right. And even though different front-end frameworks might package the syntax a little differently they can't change the underlying EVM principles of operation. So it will always be either a) got a transaction hash or b) got information.